# PHP .dat Processing vs MySQL Query Speed

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

To monitor spambots and unnecessary crawlers / bots / scrapers, I set up honeypots with `rel=nofollow` links and hidden links. Now I have nearly 200 IP to block within a week. I do not intend to use .htaccess since .htaccess file will later become very large.

I am storing these IP in MySQL and am querying it for blocked IP before any page load. This is OK for now but will become slow as the rows increase. I found people storing such data in `.dat` file to avoid hitting DB and perhaps faster search. I have never worked on `.dat` files before, but it seems like .txt files only !

My question is :

- is storing blocked IP in `.dat` file and processing it with PHP faster than storing it in `mysql` and querying it?
- Which of the two methods are more RAM intensive?
- Is checking blocked IP like this better than blocking IP in `.htaccess` file (for thousands of IP) or Apache can easily handle large `htaccess` file?

Comment: If you store in a text file you'll have to open it,  read it, and analyse its contents. A sql database is optimisedfor these kinds of operations.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by '.dat' file that you mean a file accessed directly by php using fopen()/file_get_copntents()/file() etc?

This is a very dangerous approach. Each PHP instance doesn't know what the other PHP instances are doing meaning that in order to avoid clobbering the contents of the file you need to imlpement locking - which will cause your scripts to slow down and use more memory. There's also a potential risk of deadlocks and timeouts.

Given that the list is likely to continue growing, in order to be able to block the access without too much overhead it will need to be actively pruned. Using a DBMS provides a method for managing the data more effectively.

If it were me, I'd use fail2ban - but that depends on having root access to the server.